# Does Adwords use Geolocation in AdRank?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, geolocation, geotargeting

I'm running a national campaign for an online retailer. They are focusing on improving sales in Michigan.  Their national ads are currently showing in Michigan.

Do I get any value from adding Michigan using geo location? Would a new campaign using the exact same ads but focusing on Michigan make any difference?

Comment: Totally embarrassed by the grammar!